# react native: there is another method like groupBy that can filter uniq only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I'm having a problem that the groupBy filter of lodash is not focused enough and it's probably returning everything I have in `Containers_Description`
If for example both `Containers_Description_4` and `Containers_Description_7` appear then it does not filter them for some reason.
Is there another way to target filtering by Containers_Description only?

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy'

let groupedTypeSikum = groupBy(typesikum, "Containers_Description")
```

Comment: Please add an example data, and expected result.

Comment: there is another lodash function that can give me the "Containers_Description" only ?
like uniq or something ?